# What indeterminant forms do L’Hospital’s Rule apply to?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, indeterminate-forms

I am studying L’Hospital’s Rule and I know that it applies to indeterminant forms of the kind:

1. $\frac{0}{0}$
2. $\frac{\pm \infty}{\pm \infty}$

However, what if you have the form say $\frac{0}{\infty}$ or $\frac{\infty}{0}$, does L’Hospital’s Rule still apply?

More formally, if you have $$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty \text{ and } \lim_{x \rightarrow b} g(x) = 0,$$ then is it still true that 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}~~?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{0}{\infty} = 0$ and $\frac{\infty}{0} = \infty$. These are not indetermined forms.

Comment: $\infty/0$ may also be $-\infty$ or undefined, depending on *how* the denominator tends to zero.

Comment: It is defined. The sign depends on various situations: you can have $\frac{+\infty}{0^+}, \frac{-\infty}{0^+}, \frac{+\infty}{0^-}$ and so on. Essentially the result is $\infty$ with some sign, but it's not indetermined. It's up to you to see in every case how your functions behave to get the right sign.

Comment: What about $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{x \sin (1/x)}$?

Comment: If you set $y = 1/x$ then that is equivalent to $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{-y\log y }{\sin y}$, which does not exist as the numerator goes to $-\infty$ but the limit of the denominator does not exist.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my point! It's an example of a limit of type $-\infty/0$ which is *undefined*, not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: I see what you mean. Anyway there is a difference between "undefined" and "non-existent". I hope this has helped.